# Search questions tagged to only single Tag

Tags: support, questions, search

I want to search questions tagged to only one tag.
Like as example if I search questions from tags specifying one tag as "java", the result displays the questions tagged with "java" and other tags. But what if I want to search questions tagged with only single tag "java" and no other tags with it, can it be possible for such question search scenario?

Comment: I can't see any way for this to be useful. Excluding certain tags as shown below, yes, but __all__ tags, no.

Comment: If you're looking to edit, please don't start retagging loads of old useless questions... almost every new question probably needs editing and that's a much more useful way to contribute, just makes sure you fix the title/body whilst you're at it.

Comment: @dav_i I was searching for this functionality tonight and found this post.  I thought I'd share why I think it's useful (2 years later ;-).  I'm looking at python questions.  But their is a torrent of questions regarding libraries I have no clue how to use.  I'm looking for pure python questions like ones about list comprehensions and dictionaries and how to build classes.  I figure I can clear the noise if I limited my search to a single tag.  Martijn Pieters' answer looks like it will do the trick tho.

Comment: This is a great example of the `x,y` problem. What you think you want to do is not only not possible, but not what you really want. Eliminating all tags but one is bound to remove things that you didn't want to remove; what about all the questions tagged `python` and the issue they're dealing with, like `[String]` or `[loops]` or the specific version of python (like `[python-3.x]`)? A better way to address your issue is to notice which tags are reoccurring that you don't want (`[numpy]`,`[pandas]`,`[pycharm]`) and explicitly exclude those tags, which is what Martijn Pieters♦ showed how to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, there is no feature to limit search to just one tag.

You can only explicitly exclude tags, so you *can* search for `[java] -[android]` and get any posts that are tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) but do not have the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag.

You can always use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow) for more specialist queries. I've created one that [searches for questions with a specific single tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/204368/all-questions-with-a-single-tag). The usual Data Explorer caveats apply; the database is refreshed just once a week on Sundays, so query results do not reflect more recent changes on the site.

Comment: I am receiving the following error while running your query with 'javascript' tag:
"The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information."

Comment: @Dorad: that is hardly an onerous query; it's a simple column match. The whole dataexplorer server appears to  be having issues, I can't even log in with an external OpenID endpoint right now.